Mahalanobis distance as a bound on the Euclidean distance
Can someone please help me figure out how to prove (or disprove) the following statement?

Consider

A random point $\mathbf{M}$ in 2D space, normally distributed with mean $\mathbf{m}=(m_x, m_y)$ and covariance $\Sigma_M$.
A discrete set of points $P = \{p_i = (x_i, y_i) : i=1, 2, ..., n\}$ all having distinct Mahalanobis distances from $\mathbf{m}$.
A scalar positive threshold $r$.

Then the point in $P$ with the largest Mahalanobis distance from $\mathbf{m}$ is also the one with the highest probability of being at least $r$ away from $\mathbf{M}$

The 1D case is trivially true, as the area under the Gaussian in an interval of width 2r decreases monotonically as the distance from the mean increases, and in 1D the Mahalanobis distance is just the Euclidean one measured in standard deviations. But I am not quite sure how to attack the 2D case (and then generalize to 3D).
Any help appreciated.
